# 7: How to import simple channel-level rss data to the parent feed node created by Feeds module?

Tags: 7, rules, feeds, importing-exporting

The Feeds module is properly importing Child/Feed Item-level data to the generated Child-level Drupal nodes.

What I need now is to import Parent/Channel/Feed-level info to the Parent/Feed=level Drupal entity that the Feeds module also creates.

It would/should be a simple mapping that imports the Parent/Channel-level RSS feed data (channel title, channel description, channel image etc) to the Parent/Feed Drupal node that the Feeds module creates (NOT the item/child-level nodes that it also creates.)

```
<channel>
  <title>Some Feed Title</title>
  <description>Some description...</description>
  <image>
   <url>http://example.com/image.jpg</url>
  </image>

  <item>item info starts here....</item>
  <item>more item stuff here....</item>
</channel>
```

It seems the Feeds module does not account for this.

- I see mention of creating a new parser (https://drupal.org/node/622700) but that is still only affecting the creation of the child/item-level nodes yes?
- On that same page I see "Create a feed node programmatically" but that ignores the core Feeds child/item-level functionality yes?
- I have installed the Rules module (and its Feeds patch) and am able to get from the $source object the created Parent/Channel-level node ID that Feeds generates when importing the feed, but I don't have any of the feed's data to send to that ID (I don't think anyway - there is a FeedsFetcherResult numerical value but not sure that that is of any help.)

Any assistance in pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated! Seems like a common need related to this module but oddly haven't seen any solutions out there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the patch supplied in https://drupal.org/node/1689374?